# Why is there a difference between datetime.utcnow() and datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timestamp, utc

As you can see from the snippet below, there's a one hour difference between the two method. What is the reason ?

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import time

def timestamp2date(timestamp):
    # function converts a UTC timestamp into Europe/Zurich Gregorian date
    DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    utcTimeStamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp)).replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))
    return utcTimeStamp.astimezone(timezone('Europe/Zurich')).strftime(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)

timeStampUTC_1 = time.mktime(datetime.utcnow().timetuple())
print(timeStampUTC_1)
print(timestamp2date(timeStampUTC_1))
timeStampUTC_2 = time.mktime(datetime.now(timezone('UTC')).timetuple())
print(timeStampUTC_2)
print(timestamp2date(timeStampUTC_2))
print(timeStampUTC_2 - timeStampUTC_1)

# 1504385450.0
# 2017-09-03 00:50:50   this the right time
# 1504389050.0
# 2017-09-03 01:50:50
# 3600.0
```

Comment: I did run the code under python 3.6 on my Windows 10 laptop nnd on my Android smartphone in QPython which executes a Python 3.2 interpreter and I obtain the same difference. My local timezone is Europe/Zurich.

Comment: ... but even with US/Pacific as timezone, the difference is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `datetime.timetuple()` sets `dst=-1` if the `datetime` is not offset aware and `dst=0 or 1` when it is offset aware.

From the documentation:

> The `tm_isdst` flag of the result is set according to the `dst()` method: `tzinfo` is `None` or `dst()` returns `None`, `tm_isdst` is set to `-1`; else if `dst()` returns a non-zero value, `tm_isdst` is set to `1`; else `tm_isdst` is set to `0`.

```
In []:
datetime.utcnow()
Out[]:
datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 2, 23, 9, 12, 715042)

In []:
print(datetime.utcnow().dst())
Out[]:
None

In []:
datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
Out[]:
datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 2, 23, 9, 15, 856983, tzinfo=<UTC>)

In []:
datetime.now(timezone('UTC')).dst()
Out[]
datetime.timedelta(0)

In []:
datetime(2017, 9, 2, 23, 9, 15, 856983).timetuple()
Out[]:
time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=23, tm_min=9, 
                 tm_sec=15, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=245, tm_isdst=-1)
                                                             ^^
In []:
datetime(2017, 9, 2, 23, 9, 15, 856983, timezone('UTC')).timetuple()
Out[]:
time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=23, tm_min=9, 
                 tm_sec=15, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=245, tm_isdst=0)
                                                             ^
```

This changes the `timestamp` that `time.mktime()` generates because `mktime` treats `-1` unknown and uses localtime, so may calculate `dst=1` and hence they could be an 1 hour different (`3600s`):

```
In []:
time.mktime(datetime(2017, 9, 2, 23, 9, 15, 856983).timetuple())
Out[]:
1504411755.0

In []:
time.mktime(datetime(2017, 9, 2, 23, 9, 15, 856983, timezone('UTC')).timetuple())
Out[]:
1504415355.0
```

Comment: From the documentation: In calls to mktime(), tm_isdst may be set to 1 when daylight savings time is in effect, and 0 when it is not. A value of -1 indicates that this is not known, and will usually result in the correct state being filled in.

Comment: @Jean-PierreSchnyder The documentation states for `mktime`: "Its argument is the struct_time or full 9-tuple (since the dst flag is needed; use -1 as the dst flag if it is unknown) which expresses the time in local time, **not UTC**." So it will correct for `localtime` if you give it `-1` but you've passed in a `UTC` time, so you get the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the result of my further exploration of the timezone concept associated with the daylight saving time flag. The code is pretty straightforward.

To summarize the results, there's a right way to handle date/time information:

1. Date/time object must be localized
2. If localized correctly, the date/time object shows right daylight saving time information
3. This is reflected when you convert your localized date/time object to a UTC date/time object which is by definition DST agnostic
4. All those considerations are particularly relevant when, for example, you access a stock or currency historical minute rate API

code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import time

print("---- Winter time (CET=Central European Time) ----")
dateStr = "2014-02-28 22:28:15"
datetimeObjUnlocalized = datetime.strptime(dateStr, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print('UNL: ' + datetimeObjUnlocalized.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"))
print('     datetimeObjUnlocalized-->tm_isdst=' + str(datetimeObjUnlocalized.timetuple()[8]))
datetimeObjZH = timezone('Europe/Zurich').localize(datetimeObjUnlocalized)
print('ZH:  ' + datetimeObjZH.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"))
print('     datetimeObjZH-->tm_isdst=' + str(datetimeObjZH.timetuple()[8]))
print("UTC: " + datetimeObjZH.astimezone(timezone('UTC')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"))

print("\n---- Summer time (CEST=Central European Summer Time) ----")
dateStr = "2014-06-28 22:28:15"
datetimeObjUnlocalized = datetime.strptime(dateStr, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print('UNL: ' + datetimeObjUnlocalized.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"))
print('     datetimeObjUnlocalized-->tm_isdst=' + str(datetimeObjUnlocalized.timetuple()[8]))
datetimeObjZH = timezone('Europe/Zurich').localize(datetimeObjUnlocalized)
print('ZH:  ' + datetimeObjZH.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"))
print('     datetimeObjZH-->tm_isdst=' + str(datetimeObjZH.timetuple()[8]))
print("UTC: " + datetimeObjZH.astimezone(timezone('UTC')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"))
```

[image: Console output]